# Нужна помощь с пониманием данного примера C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Увидел в видео такую часть кода

```
var randomTile = Random.Range(0,6) == 3 ? mountineTile : grassTile;
```

Можете объяснить данную конструкцию?
Random.Range понимаю, а вот эту часть уже нет " = 3 ? mountineTile : grassTile;"

Для чего вопросительный знак, двоеточие. Заранее спасибо вам

Comment: тринарный оператор https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: А разве в этом выражении не должно быть Random.Range(0,6) == 3 ?

Comment: Да, Tupelo Honey, вы правы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В основном применяют для сокращения/упрощения кода. Данное выражение эквивалентно:

```
var randomTile;
if (Random.Range(0,6) == 3) // может всё таки равно, а не присвоение?
{
  randomTile = mountineTile;
}
else
{
  randomTile = grassTile;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, коротко и ясно

Answer (score 4):

Условный оператор `?:`, также называемый тернарным, вычисляет логическое выражение и в зависимости от полученного значения `true` или `false` возвращает результат одного из двух соответствующих выражений, как показано в следующем примере.

```
string GetWeatherDisplay(double tempInCelsius) => tempInCelsius < 20.0 ? "Cold." : "Perfect!";

Console.WriteLine(GetWeatherDisplay(15));  // output: Cold.
Console.WriteLine(GetWeatherDisplay(27));  // output: Perfect!
```

Как показано в предыдущем примере, синтаксис условного оператора выглядит следующим образом.

```
condition ? consequent : alternative
```

Выражение `condition` должно принимать значение `true` или `false`. Если `condition` принимает значение true, вычисляется выражение `consequent`, а результат становится результатом операции. Если `condition` принимает значение `false`, вычисляется выражение `alternative`, а результат становится результатом операции. Вычисляется только выражение `consequent` или `alternative`.

Условный оператор имеет правую ассоциативность, то есть выражение формы.

```
a ? b : c ? d : e
```

вычисляется как

```
a ? b : (c ? d : e)
```

Вы можете использовать следующий мнемонический прием, чтобы запомнить, как оценивается условный оператор:

```
is this condition true ? yes : no
```

[Документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Теперь всё куда яснее